# display all document on php

Tags: php, mongodb

I would like to display all documents of the collection : article i have made this :

```
<?php
    try {
           $connection = new MongoClient();
           $database   = $connection->selectDB('Myblog');
           $collection = $database->selectCollection('articles');
         } 
            catch(MongoConnectionException $e) {
            die("Failed to connect to database ".$e->getMessage());
    }

    $query=array();
    $cursor=$collection->find($query);

    foreach ($cursor as $doc) {     
        echo " Title is : ".$article['title']."";
    }
?>
```

but i have just this :

> Title is : Test
>   Title is : Test
>   Title is : Test

This is my collection :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55bd3fb50faaf28804b7acd9"), "title" : "Test1", "content" : "hello", saved_at" : ISODate("2015-08-01T21:52:53.420Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55bd3fbd0faaf2c403b7acda"), "title" : "Test2", "content" : "hey", "saved_at" : ISODate("2015-08-01T21:53:01.706Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55bd3fc90faaf2c103b7acd9"), "title" : "Test3", "content" : "hello test", "saved_at" : ISODate("2015-08-01T21:53:13.225Z") }
```

Thanks with the help

Answer (score 0):

What is it that is missing? You are only refering to the `title` in you output from the `echo` command. If you want the other fields, you must refer to them, i.e. (`$article['content']`, etc...)

Comment: the problem is that : it appears that test,test,test  and I want to test 1,test2,test3

Answer (score 0):

use

```
  foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
      echo "Title is : " . $doc['title'];
  }
```